# Angular2 with video.js error no compatible source

Tags: angular, video.js

VIDEOJS: ERROR: (CODE:4 MEDIA_ERR_SRC_NOT_SUPPORTED) No compatible source was found for this video.

I am trying to play video in angular 2 project.
Here is my code:

```
import {Component, ElementRef, OnInit, OnDestroy} from 'angular2/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'my-app',
    template: `

    <video id="example_video_1" class="video-js vjs-default-skin"
        controls preload="auto" width="640" height="264"
        poster="http://video-js.zencoder.com/oceans-clip.png"
        data-setup='{"example_option":true}'>
        <source src="C:/Users/knare/Downloads/Joey Montana - Picky.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
        <source src="C:/Users/knare/Downloads/Joey Montana - Picky.webm" type="video/webm" />
        <source src="C:/Users/knare/Downloads/Joey Montana - Picky.ogv" type="video/ogg" />
        <p class="vjs-no-js">To view this video please enable JavaScript, and consider upgrading to a web browser that <a href="http://videojs.com/html5-video-support/" target="_blank">supports HTML5 video</a></p>
    </video>

    `
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {

    private _elementRef: ElementRef
    private videoJSplayer : VideoJSPlayer

    constructor(elementRef: ElementRef) {
        this._elementRef = elementRef
    }

    ngOnInit() {
        var player = videojs('example_video_1', { /* Options */ }, function() {
              console.log('Good to go!');

              this.play(); // if you don't trust autoplay for some reason 

              // How about an event listener? 
              this.on('ended', function() {
                console.log('awww...over so soon?');
              });
            });
    }

    ngOnDestroy() {
        console.log('Deinit - Destroyed Component')
        this.videoJSplayer.dispose()
    }
}
```

Comment: Eclipse is just the IDE you are using and tells us nothing. Sets the question tags to include the programming language you are asking about. Please take the time to read the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) to learn how Stack Overflow works.

Answer (score 2):

You should be using `ngAfterViewInit()` and not `ngOnInit()` this is called before the view is initialized so videojs has no element to select.

Make sure you have installed `npm install --save @types/videojs`

Example:

```
import { AfterViewInit, Component, ElementRef, OnInit, OnDestroy, ViewChild } from 'angular2/core';


@Component({
    selector: 'my-app',
    template: `

    <video #video id="example_video_1" class="video-js vjs-default-skin"
        controls preload="auto" width="640" height="264"
        poster="http://video-js.zencoder.com/oceans-clip.png"
        data-setup='{"example_option":true}'>
        <source src="C:/Users/knare/Downloads/Joey Montana - Picky.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
        <source src="C:/Users/knare/Downloads/Joey Montana - Picky.webm" type="video/webm" />
        <source src="C:/Users/knare/Downloads/Joey Montana - Picky.ogv" type="video/ogg" />
        <p class="vjs-no-js">To view this video please enable JavaScript, and consider upgrading to a web browser that <a href="http://videojs.com/html5-video-support/" target="_blank">supports HTML5 video</a></p>
    </video>

    `
})
export class AppComponent implements AfterViewInit, OnInit, OnDestroy {
    @ViewChild() video;
    private _elementRef: ElementRef
    private videoJSplayer : VideoJSPlayer

    constructor(elementRef: ElementRef) {
        this._elementRef = elementRef
    }

    AfterViewInit() {
        var player = videojs(this.video.nativeElement, { /* Options */ }, function() {
              console.log('Good to go!');

              this.play(); // if you don't trust autoplay for some reason 

              // How about an event listener? 
              this.on('ended', function() {
                console.log('awww...over so soon?');
              });
            });
    }

    ngOnDestroy() {
        console.log('Deinit - Destroyed Component')
        this.videoJSplayer.dispose()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like an issue with accessing the video, below code is working

```
<video id="example_video_1" class="video-js vjs-default-skin"
        controls preload="auto" width="640" height="264"
        poster="http://video-js.zencoder.com/oceans-clip.png"
        data-setup='{"example_option":true}'>
        <source src="http://vjs.zencdn.net/v/oceans.mp4" type="video/mp4" />

        <p class="vjs-no-js">To view this video please enable JavaScript, and consider upgrading to a web browser that <a href="http://videojs.com/html5-video-support/" target="_blank">supports HTML5 video</a></p>
    </video>
```

Check : https://github.com/mbalex99/ng2-videojs/blob/master/app/app.ts