# How to integrate video.js and open model when video completes in angular 4

Tags: angular, video.js

I am using video.js to play a video i want to open a model when video completes in angular 4

Comment: Use the on ended event, example code can be found https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39229933/angular2-with-video-js-error-no-compatible-source/40391350#40391350

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can listen to the on ended event see example below:

```
videojs(el, {}, function() {
    this.on('ended', function() {
        // Call to open model here
    });
});
```

Comment: Any way to set html as content to model?

Comment: Could you add code examples to your question, then I may be able to help.

Comment: I have to show html in model.... if i m using this.createModel(<h1>Hello</h1>).....it shows it as  <h1>Hello</h1>... i want to show just Hello

Comment: Can you show me the code for createModel? How are you inserting the HTML into the component?

Comment: Can you add the code for the `new ModalDialog()` class?

Comment: I realise now that it's part of video.js. You will need to declare the ModalDialog. I will try and setup a demo.

Comment: That's great. Mark the answer as accepted if you believe it's the right answer to your initial question.

Comment: could you please look into this issue https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45355524/video-js-give-error-youtube-is-undefined-while-playing-youtube-video

Answer (score 0):

```
   this.player.on('ended', function() {
  const options = {
    content:'<button>Hello World</button>',
    label:'the label',
    uncloseable:true
  };
  const ModalDialog = videojs.getComponent('ModalDialog');
  const modal = new ModalDialog(this, options);
  this.addChild(modal);
  modal.open();
  modal.on('modalclose', function() {
    console.log('model closed');
  });
});
```

i want to disaplay button in model