# Video.js give error "youtube" is undefined while playing youtube video

Tags: angular, video.js

```
 @Component({
 selector: 'invidz-video-js-component',
 template: `
<div id="full-background">
  <video
    id="vid"
    class="video-js vjs-default-skin vjs-fullscreen vjs-big-play-centered"
    controls
    data-setup='{ "techOrder": ["youtube"]}'
  >
    <source  type="video/youtube" [src]="videoUrl"/>
  </video>
</div>
`,
   `]
    })
    export class VideoJsComponent implements OnInit, AfterViewInit {

   @Input() videoUrl: string;
  @Input() autoPlay: string;


private player: any;


 constructor() {

}

ngOnInit() {
console.log(this.autoPlay);
console.log(this.videoUrl);
}

ngAfterViewInit() {
  this.player = videojs(document.getElementById('vid'));
 this.player.on('ended', function() {

  });
 }
}
```

Video.js give error  "youtube" is undefined while playing youtube video

Error :

> video.es.js:439 VIDEOJS: ERROR: The "youtube" tech is undefined.
>   Skipped browser support check for that tech.

Comment: There is no such type as `video/youtube` unless video.js is changing that. Are you using https://github.com/videojs/videojs-youtube

Comment: yes i m using that...any idea how to resolve this

Comment: Possible duplicate of [enabling youtube playback with video.js wrapper](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17546633/enabling-youtube-playback-with-video-js-wrapper)

Answer (score 0):

This works for me with
package.json

```
    "video.js": "^7.17.0",
    "videojs-youtube": "^2.6.1",
```

js file, basically videojsYoutube does nothing but initialize Youtube Tech.

```
import videojs from "video.js";
import videojsYoutube from "videojs-youtube";
```